# How To Convert Google Client Vision Library Response To Json

Tags: python, json, google-api, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to convert the response from Google Cloud Vision API Client Library to a json format. However i get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo'
>   object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR

**Resource**

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import request
from flask import json
from util.GoogleVision import GoogleVision
from util.Convert import Convert

import base64
import requests

import os


class Vision(Resource):

    def post(self):

        googleVision = GoogleVision()

        req = request.get_json()

        url = req['url']

        result = googleVision.detectLabels(url)

        return result
```

**GoogleVision.py**

```
import os

from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

class GoogleVision():

    def detectLabels(self, uri):

        client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
        image = types.Image()
        image.source.image_uri = uri

        response = client.label_detection(image=image)
        labels = response.label_annotations

        res = MessageToJson(labels)

        return res
```

the labels variable is of type `<class'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer'>`

As you can see i am using message to json function on the labels response. But i am getting the above error.

Is there a way to convert the result to a json format?

Comment: khan, can you attach the whole code & complete error instead of a line. The current attached error says about "DESCRIPTOR" which is not used any where above

Comment: @UdayS this is the whole code

Comment: Why don't you use the [API Discovery](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started)? Look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160997/googles-vision-api-protobuf-response-object-to-python-dictionary) on how to use it with this API.

Answer (score 8):

A simple way to do it is using the Discovery API. You can create a service object using the [build()](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build) function. You will get the response as a dictionary when executing the request. Then you can convert it to JSON using `json.dumps()`.

Example with Discovery API:

```py
import json
import apiclient.discovery
import base64

class GoogleVision():

    def detectLabels(self, uri):

        # Instantiates a client
        service = apiclient.discovery.build('vision', 'v1')

        # Image file
        file_name=uri

        # Loads the image into memory
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as image:
            image_content = base64.b64encode(image.read())

            # Creates the request
            service_request = service.images().annotate(body={
                'requests': [{
                    'image': {
                        'content': image_content.decode('UTF-8')
                    },
                    'features': [{
                        'type': 'LABEL_DETECTION',
                    }]
                }]
            })

        # Execute the request  
        response = service_request.execute()

        # Convert to Json
        res_json = json.dumps(response)

        return res_json
```

If you don’t want to use the Discovery API, you can convert the response to dictionary using `MessageToDict()` function first and then to JSON with `json.dumps()`.

Example without the Discovery API using `MessageToDict()` :

```py
import json
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict

class GoogleVision():

    def detectLabels(self, uri):

        # Instantiates a client
        client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

        # Image file
        file_name=uri

        # Loads the image into memory
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as image:
            image_content = image.read()

        image = types.Image(content=image_content)

        # Performs label detection on the image file
        response = client.label_detection(image=image)       

        #Convert the response to dictionary
        response = MessageToDict(response)

        # Convert to Json
        res_json = json.dumps(response)

        return res_json
```

Comment: Using a two-step MessageToDict followed by conversion to JSON is an excellent suggestion; for me, it works better than MessageToJson when applied to Google's Vision API responses, because (at least in my hands) applying MessageToJson to the API's Protocol Buffer responses produces a string.